# Unable to create C++ projects UE5

Tags: unreal-engine5

When I attempt to make a C++ project, I get the following error.

```
"Running /opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh  -projectfiles -project="/home/mason/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject3/MyProject3.uproject" -game -engine -progress
Setting up bundled DotNet SDK
chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/../../../Binaries/ThirdParty/DotNet/6.0.302/linux/dotnet': Operation not permitted"
```

now I can run chown on the engine directory, but then I get this error:

```
Running /opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh  -projectfiles -project="/home/mason/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject3/MyProject3.uproject" -game -engine -progress
Setting up bundled DotNet SDK
Running command : dotnet Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.dll -projectfiles -project=/home/mason/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject3/MyProject3.uproject -game -engine -progress
Log file: /home/mason/.config/Epic/UnrealBuildTool/Log_GPF.txt

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: Android.
See the log file for detailed information


Generating CLion project files:
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
Targets with a unique build environment cannot be built with an installed engine.
Running Manjaro Linux, built UE5 from source.
```

I can also create blueprints just fine, but anything to do with C++ fails, and I'm not sure it will build either.